# PDI - Can I implement Exist logic in pentaho? Or is there any way?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I wonder, is there any way to implement exist logic using PDI like in Query Script below 
 `EXIST (SELECT a.product FROM store a, struck b WHERE b.product = a.product)` to check is the data exist in files (CSV)? 
I know PDI has provide design tools like `Table Exist`, `File Exist` and `Check if a column exist` but that tools only work in DB Table and File not data inside the File.

Comment: your question is not clear..
Do your want to compare csv data with table data?

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Well, I have edit the question.

Comment: i can't see any changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the records in the file (or sql, or REST client, or,...) and filter only if it is not zero.

[image]

Comment: okay, look at this Script `WHERE x.prdcd IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (SELECT p.productid FROM product_filter p WHERE x.prdcd = p.productid) AND NOT (x.qty = 0 AND t.productid IS NULL);` and this is what I write `https://imgur.com/a/yN8873X` It's correct?

Comment: You only, as data owner, can say if it's true after a test. But  it's a rather sqly answer.